# I want to lock a part of a async method in python basically it should be a(name based lock) where name is passed as argument to the method

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio, contextmanager, locks

In the below code the test() function waits for the request from UI as the request is received in  JSON form it creates a task for every request by calling handle() fucntion

```
async def test():
     loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
     req = await receiver.recv_string()
     logger.debug(f"Request received {req}")
     req_json = json.loads(req)
     logger.debug("Await create_task")
     loop.create_task(handle(req_json))

async def handle(req_json_):
     req_name = req_json_.get(req_name)
    # acquire lock here based on req_name if request comes with different name acquire the lock 
    # but if the request comes with same name block the request  
    # untill the req for that name is completed if the request is already completed then acquire 
    # the lock  with that name 
     logger.info(f"Request finished with req name {req_name} for action patch stack")
```

How can achieve this with asyncio  module or any other way in python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that all you need to do is maintain a dictionary of locks whose keys are the names given by variable `req_name` and whose values are the corresponding locks. If the key `reg_name` is not already in the dictionary, then a new lock for that key will be added:

```py
import asyncio
from collections import defaultdict


# dictionary of locks
locks = defaultdict(asyncio.Lock)

async def handle(req_json_):
    req_name = req_json_.get(req_name)
    # acquire lock here based on req_name if request comes with different name acquire the lock 
    # but if the request comes with same name block the request  
    # untill the req for that name is completed if the request is already completed then acquire 
    # the lock  with that name
    # Get lock from locks dictionary with name req_name. If it
    # does not exit, then create a new lock and store it with key
    # req_name and return it:
    lock = locks[req_name]
    async with lock:
        # do whatever needs to be done:
        ...
    logger.info(f"Request finished with req name {req_name} for action patch stack")
```

**Update**

If you need to timeout the attempt to acquire a lock, then create a coroutine that acquires the passed lock argument in conjunctions with a call to `asyncio.wait_for` with a suitable *timeout* argument:

```py
import asyncio
from collections import defaultdict


async def acquire_lock(lock):
    await lock.acquire()

# dictionary of locks
locks = defaultdict(asyncio.Lock)

async def handle(req_json_):
    req_name = req_json_.get(req_name)
    lock = locks[req_name]
    # Try to acquire the lock but timeout after 1 second:
    try:
        await asyncio.wait_for(acquire_lock(lock), timeout=1.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        # Here if the lockout could not be acquired:
        ...
    else:
        # Do whatever needs to be done
        # The lock must now be explicitly released:
        try:
            ...
            logger.info(f"Request finished with req name {req_name} for action patch stack")
        finally:
            lock.release()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response can you please also tell how timeout could be implemented for the locks in this scenario

Comment: See the update to the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answers also to use a `collections.defaultdict` dictionary, which is probably more efficient than using the `dict.setdefault` method, which would always create a `Lock`  instance whether the key was present or not and then end up discarding it.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer can you please also tell how to timeout the lock which is already in execution and if it gets struck somewhere in the process or if because of some error it doesnt reach the lock.release() statement in th code ? thanks

Comment: First, there should not already be a lock that is acquired without going through this code, so it is already being timed. Second, I did not say anything about your last question about how to timeout a lock acquisition because you are new to this site. But now I will tell you that it is considered improper to keep on adding new questions on top of an existing question that as already been answered, namely how to handle a "named lock", which I believe I have successfully answered. (more ...)

Comment: If lock acquisition is going through the code I posted above, the `try/finally` block guarantees that if the code within the `try` block raises an exception, the code within the `finally` block will still be unconditionally executed. (this is very basic Python). Do you see the call to `lock.release()` within that `finally` block?

Comment: I tried the updated one but in that case lock is not getting acquired it state remians unlocked but i would accept your suggestion and sorry i wasn't  aware about the best practices on this site

Comment: See [this demo Python program](https://ideone.com/ByhBCw). I had to modify the first line of your function `handle` since `req_name = req_json_.get(req_name)` did not make sense to me (what is the `req_name` field?). So I am just looking for a field named 'req_name'. I am also simulating time spent processing by passing another key `sleep_time` and am calling `handle` 3 times and forcing a timeout for one of the invocations. At the end I print out all the locks created; they are all "unlocked". Perhaps you did not do something correctly. Study this code carefully.